# Error 500 in Angularjs $http.post and webservice asmx

Tags: angularjs, web-services

I try to make a validatión with a webservice and $http from angular, the problem is an error 500 when i try to send data, if i call webservice without data works perfectly, the code:

Angularjs

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

$http.post('/CloudMobile/gpvdata.asmx/validausuario', {username: username, password: password}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                    $rootScope.datos = data[0];

                    console.log($rootScope.datos.grupo);

                    callback({success: true});

                  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                    console.log('Falla la validación en el asmx');

                  });
```

Webservice

```
[WebMethod]
        public void validausuario(string usuario, string password)

        {

            TGlobalOpClases g = miGlobal(usuario, password);

            t1ValidacionSistema val = new t1ValidacionSistema(g);

            Resultado_BD ResBD = val.Valida("SYSTEM_GPV", "DEMO", DateTime.Now);

            g.idUsuarioConsola = val.Datos.idUsuario;

            if (ResBD.ok)
            {

                t1Usuario user = new t1Usuario(g);

                Entrada_OPBD x = new Entrada_OPBD();
                x.PonLanzarEx();

                user.FichaCarga(x,g.idUsuarioConsola);
                user.GruposPertenece_Carga(x);

                string jsn = Json.Encode(user.GruposPertenece);

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(jsn);

            }
            else {

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Fallo la conexión");

            }
        }

public TGlobalOpClases miGlobal(string usuario, string password)
        //public TGlobalOpClases miGlobal()
        {
            ExEngine_Client.TGlobalOpClases global = new TGlobalOpClases();
            global.miParIniOP.password = password;
            global.miParIniOP.Usuario = usuario;
            global.Server = "192.168.0.16\\sql";
            global.DataBase = "Desarrollo";
            global.Conecta();

            return global;
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: you get `500` when **there is some error on server**. can you check in logs if there is any or debug your server code.

Comment: This might not be the correct answer but once I had a similar issue it was solved simple by adding `{"username": username, "password": password}` inverted commas like this (: or changing `Content-Type` to `''`.

Comment: I added the quotes and I still get the same error.

Comment: In the server log appear this error: 

2016-04-12 10:38:41 ::1 POST /CloudMobile/gpvdata.asmx/validausuario - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/49.0.2623.112+Safari/537.36 http://localhost/cloudmobile/app/www/ 500 0 0 265